# Does this book use non-mainstream stochastic analysis constructions and is thus perhaps not a good start?

Tags: integration, stochastic-calculus

I'm attempting to read a book on stochastic calculus by D.H. Fremlin, which is the [6th volume](https://www1.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/mtcont.htm) of his treatise on measure theory encompassing all kinds of topics related it.

Before I make a very significant time investment, I'd be curious about how much his way to setup stochastic integration differs from more traditional and standard approaches, in two ways:

- Is his approach to construct it non-mainstream?
- is the final outcome perhaps a slightly different mathematical object then the standard one (e.g. in *Sondermann D. - Introduction to Stochastic Calculus for Finance. A New Didactic Approach* it seems to me that a different non-mainstream  construction is used, but which nevertheless leads to the standard outcome)? Resp. how does it compare with the theory as it is setup in *[Shalizi C. - Almost None of the Theory of Stochastic Processes](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Ecshalizi/almost-none/)*?)

It seems to me that the author bases his construction on measure algebras, which he introduces in volume 3. My level of measure theory is somewhere along his volume 2. While I do not mind reading up things from volume 3 to follow his exposition on stochastic calculus, I would very much mind if I found that afterwards I can't talk with some of my colleagues anymore, who to a course in stochastic calculus that went the traditional way, because we each speak "language" that is not quite the same, since the text I read was too non-standard. Is there such a danger?

---

Here is an excerpt from the first chapter of volume 6 (called chapter 61 there):
*I begin with an attempt to give a coherent and complete description of the principal form of stochastic
integration which will be investigated in this volume.
As elsewhere in probability theory, it is customary to set this material out in terms of ordinary random
variables, that is, measurable functions defined on probability spaces. We find immediately, however, that
while integrands and integrators may well present themselves most naturally in this form, the integrals we
construct are defined, in the cases for which this theory has been developed, in terms of convergence in
$|| \ ||_1$ or $|| \ ||_2$ or in measure, and therefore correspond not to definable functions, but to equivalence classes
of functions. Moreover, integrands and integrators can be changed on negligible sets without affecting the
values of the corresponding integrals. I believe that the theory becomes clearer and cleaner if we move
directly to operations on evolving families in $L^0$ . While this demands an initial investment by the reader
in a more abstract framework for the ideas of elementary probability theory, the translation is not difficult,
and a full exposition can be found in Chapter 36*

Here is another excerpt from chapter 4 (i.e. chapter 64):

*[We will develop] what I will call the ‘S-integral’ (645P). In fact the S-integral is much closer than the Riemann-sum integral to the standard stochastic
integral developed in [Protter 05].*

Comment: Every opinion about books is personal. So is mine : between those two books I strongly favour D. Sondermann. It is not that far off the mainstream. Rather takes a route led by Föllmer that even simplifies the introduction of the stochastic integral. The book by Fremlin is a very comprehensive treatise much too heavy for someone that wants to get introduced into stochastic analysis. In fact the stochastic integral is put into one of the last chapters. IMHO that is where sochastic analysis should start to become  interesting.

Comment: @KurtG. Thank you for your input, I will consider that. I actually don't mind long-winded intros, because I want to really know the details well and I feel many books skim over them too quickly to get to the interesting parts, disregarding that some "intellectual debt" invariably builds up which might turn out later to be problematic (though I'm not saying that Sonderman might suffer from this, since I haven't read him). A good analogy is introducing curves as maps, instead of equivalence classes of maps that have the same parametrization. [...]

Comment: The former leads to all kinds of trouble if one introduces various derived concepts - but for an ad-hoc definition works fine. I also have added another book besides Sonderman for comparision, if you would share your opinion on that, I'd been interested :).

Comment: Lastly, I want to it still leaves open the last bulleted question, which is an objective one, is still open.

Comment: All three books you found were written by obviously very hard working enthusiastic authors. If you share their enthusiasm (quite understandably) go for it. There is no reason to hesitate.